# Model Blur at the corner when rotate in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new in OpenGl in android. I am making an application in which I am using the OpenGl Library. When I rotate the 3D object from the finger gesture then Model border is blurring. Please help me why model border is blurred on rotation and move.

```
private class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public Renderer() {
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

        build_grid(GRID_SIZE);

        if(mModel != null)
            mModel.bindTextures(mContext, gl);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        mViewWidth = (float)w;
        mViewHeight = (float)h;
        gl.glViewport(0,0,w,h);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 60.0f, mViewWidth/mViewHeight, 0.1f, 100f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        //position camera
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, mCamera.x,mCamera.y,mCamera.z, mOrigin.x,mOrigin.y,mOrigin.z, 0f,1f,0f);

        //draw_grid
        draw_grid(gl);

        //draw_model
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        gl.glTranslatef(mOrigin.x, mOrigin.y, 2);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.x, 1f, 0f, 0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.y, 0f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mRotate.z, 0f, 0f, 1f);

        if(mModel != null)
            mModel.draw(gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        if(isPictureTake) {
            IntBuffer ib=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
            ib.position(0);
            gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y+h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);
            createBitmapFromGLSurface(context);
            isPictureTake = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you say 'blurred', do you mean 'jagged'? I.e. are you talking about the borders of the white polygon in that image?

Comment: Border of the white Polygon getting blurred..

Comment: maybe, you're talking about aliasing and not blurring ?

Comment: @Max You are right...Please help me to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are [jagged (not blurred) lines because of aliasing](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2071). A way to avoid this type of aliasing is by using [Multi-Sample Anti-Aliasing (MSAA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing). Whether you can use this easily depends on the support for MSAA (or CSAA for Tegra's) on the GPU, but I believe most modern devices will support it. There are also ways to implement this manually, but that would be a more significant undertaking.

To enable it, you have to select an [EGL frame buffer configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser.html) that supports multi-sampling. I think the [config chooser that is used in libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/surfaceview/GdxEglConfigChooser.java) will give you exactly what you need: you specify the desired number of samples for MSAA (and color depth), and it tries to match a configuration that matches that specification as close as possible.